# Nested selectors performance impact and LESS

Tags: css, performance, optimization, css-selectors, less

I have been reading for the past 1.5 hours about this and still couldn't find a concise and *decisive* answer.

As far as I understood browsers parse CSS selectors from right to left.

That means a long CSS selector such as this:

```
.card .container .businesscard .pinfo li.pinfo-box span:first-child
```

is one of the least efficient lines of code to ever appear here in SO.

First of all, am I right on this one?

Secondly, I am designing a rich UI using LESS, which ultimately produces this kind of mammoth selectors out of the nested designs I am coding.

What can be done to avoid this kind of selectors? Rely on classes and IDs alone? But then again what is the purpose of using LESS if you can't write nested CSS?

Your input is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're over complicating your selectors.  Is the `.container` necessary in that selector?  Are you really planning to have `span:first-child` styled differently if `.container` isn't one of its ancestors?

Comment: I see. I guess I nested far too deep in.

Comment: Oddly enough, a similar question for Sass/SCSS was asked just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805324/how-bad-is-it-in-practice-to-over-nest-selectors-in-sass-scss

Comment: Huh. I probably did find it because I was searching for LESS.Thanks - it has some great information.

Comment: That said, would it be possible to enhance the LESS parser to breakdown nesting and optimize selectors? For example limit it to 3 levels tops. Deeper than that it would break the extract the nest from right to left. Possible? Reliable? What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct. Browsers evaluate selectors from right to left. It will try to find a `span` inside a `li.pinfo-box` and so on.

One rule of thumb to folllow when writing LESS is: **do not nest more than 3-4 levels.**

This will prevent your selectors from growing to big, while you will still be able to benefit from the nesting feature in LESS.

A good example of "useless" nesting is when styling lists. Sometimes I write the selectors like this:

`#wrapper .blog-post ul`, `#wrapper .blog-post ul li`

Is it really necessary to specify that the `li` **must** be inside a `ul`? It will probably be enough writing:

`#wrapper .blog-post li`

All of this is good to know. BUT: This is not the first thing to dive into when trying to optimize your sites performance. Spend some time lower the number of request or something else instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. We still don't have a working site, only designing UI at the moment. You might want to correct that "left to right" at the beginning of your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Selector parsing and matching is unlikely to be a big factor unless you have pretty unusual content. I would suggest using whatever is maintainable and gets the job done, up until the point where testing shows a performance issue. Then I'd get out a profiler (on OSX I'd use Instruments, but there should be a decent one available for most platforms) and attach it to the browser; if selector matching shows up high on the profile, then look into replacing slow selectors with faster ones (id selectors are definitely a good bet).

Comment: That's interesting - I never used a tool like this before. I will look for one on Windows. Thanks!