# How to change mixin values based off dynamic class being applied

Tags: sass

I created a simple mixin to group hover and focus. Now, I actually want to only apply focus to the mixin if the user uses the keyboard to tab through the site. How can this be accomplished?

My original mixin

```
@mixin hover { &:hover, &;focus { @content; }}
```

What I want to update to ( something like this that works )

```
@mixin hover { &:hover { @content; }}

body.user-tabbing {
    @mixin hover { &:hover, &:focus { @content; }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to provide conditional functionality for the separation of the `:hover` and `:focus` selectors, something like;

```
@mixin user-cue($type) {

   @if ($type == hover) {
      &:hover { @content }
   }
   @if ($type == focus) {
      &:focus { @content }
   }
   @else {
      &:hover, &:focus { @content }
   }

}
```

Then usage scenarios;

```
.class1 { @mixin user-cue(hover) { color: red }   // Hover only
.class2 { @mixin user-cue(focus) { color: green } // Focus only
.class3 { @mixin user-cue() { color: blue }       // Both Hover & Focus
```

Oh and in your example the `body.selector` would be redundant and you could lose the `body.` portion. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Awesome - let me try this and see what happens! I added the body tag in there just so I can reference were the class was getting added, I wasn't sure if it mattered vs a direct parent. Thanks!

Comment: Careful with those order-of-inception descendant specificity selectors, if they get too complicated you'll take a performance hit on large applications. Just a [side tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805324/how-bad-is-it-in-practice-to-over-nest-selectors-in-sass-scss) for easier maintenance and simpler painting passes on the browser.